# Q: How to call a function which needs arguments from child in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app and I need to execute a function to change a state in the parent component. Im calling the function from a child of a child.

The structure looks like (Parent->Child->Child).

I am passing the function as a props. How should I do it correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: show code indicating what have you tried till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Child1 onPress={()=>console.log("on press from parent")}/>      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

child 1

```
export const Child1 = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Child2 onPress={props.onPress}/>
  </View>)
```

child2

```
export const Child2 = (props) => (
  <Button
    onPress={props.onPress}
    title="Press Me"
  >)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly pass the argument to the function called from props.
Just as done in the submitHandler used in the below child component.

### Parent

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Parent extends React.Component{
  state={
    name:""
  }
  nameHandler=(userName)=>{
    this.setState({
      name:userName
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
          <Greeting askName={this.nameHandler}/>
         <Text>hello {this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

### Child

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button,TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default const Greeting=(props)=>{

  let [userName,setUsername]=useState("");

  const textHandler=(text)=>{
    setUsername(text);
  }

  const sumbmitHandler=()=>{
    props.askName(userName);
  }


  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Enter your name." onChangeText={textHandler}/>
      <Button onPress={sumbmitHandler} title="submit"/>
    </View>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test=(param)=>{ // parent component function
   // do action with param
}
<Test> // parent component

<Test2 doAction={(item)=>this.test(item)}/> // child component import

</Test> 

const Test2=({doAction})=>{   // child component

<Test3 onClick={(item)=>doAction(item)}/>// sub child component

}
```

Comment: Kindly could you explain how your code achieve the result.